# when I try to run my emulator in android Studio I got this error below ?how to resolve that

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library

Could not find aapt2-osx.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.2-5309881).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-osx.jar

then I tried to download apt-proto-0.3.1.jar ,then I tried to install the jar file on Mac and also I got another error below:
The Java JAR file"aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar"
could not be launched.
check the Console for possible error message.

Comment: what version of OS X are you running?

Comment: OS Catalina version 10.15.6